# Ordenação no Crystal Report com sub relatórios

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

Eu tenho em meu relatório 2 subs relatórios mas eu quero ordenar pelo campo "Aluno" do Main Report mas não estou conseguindo, mesmo eu já trazendo da consulta ele ordenado com eu gostaria.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tentei ordenar pelo *Group Section* do menu *Insert* mas também obtive sucesso.

Comment: Tentou ordenar pelo Record (registro) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá. Se eu entendi bem, você que ordenar pelo nome do aluno, certo? Nesse caso você deve agrupar pelo nome do aluno, e não pelo UserID.